# Back Button Doesn't Work When I switched to another ViewController inside of TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewcontroller

Back Button Doesn't Work When I switch to another ViewController inside of TabBarController and trying to go back.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let detailVC = NewDetailController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
    }
```

I think the problem is in the way how I am creating detailVC. But not sure what's wrong.

Creating TabBarController:

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // New View Controller

    let newController = NewController()
    let newNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newController)

    viewControllers = [newNavController]
} }
```

Set UITabBarController as initial in AppDelegate:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let mainVC = MainTabBarController()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)

    return true
}
```

[BackButton which doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjJi3.png)

Before I set UITabBarController as my rootVC everything worked fine.

PS: I am not using a storyboard. Everything is done programatically.

Comment: share some more insights plz

Comment: what do you mean when you say "doesn't work". nothing happens at all?

Comment: Yes. Nothing happens.

Comment: Plese create the detail VC like this: let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailVC") as! NewDetailController, detailVC is the identifier for storyboard

Comment: storyboard? I am not using a storyboard in my project at all. Not sure you give me a good advice. 

Everything is done programatically.

Comment: TabBarController is not able to embed in UINavigationController

Comment: Show your back button code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh Well
Thanks to Muhammad he gave me a crucial point.

The problem is that I am embedding my TabBarController into UINavigationController in AppDelegate.

When I remove UINavigationController everything works great!

```
    let mainVC = MainTabBarController()
    window?.rootViewController = mainVC
```